# Request latency from GAE to EC2 / S3?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, bandwidth, latency

I'm looking for some statistics on HTTP request latency from `GAE (UrlFetch HTTP, no-cache) -> EC2 (LBS: [[Jetty / Apache]])`

Has someone done such measurements / has read a post about it somewhere and will be willing to share?

Thank you,
Maxim.